# requests error message CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to web scrape an internet site. Yesterday it was working fine but since today I receive an error message which is : SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)

I don't know why I get this message today ?

I look for solution on internet and found 2 solutions.
The 1st one was to do `pip install --upgrade certifi`which was not helpful

The 2nd one was to do:

```
response = requests.post(url, 
                         headers=headers,
                         data=data,
                         verify=False #The solution found  
                         )
```

it works but it is recommended not to use this solution as a long term one.

So what should I do ? Why this message appeared ?

I must add that I am using python 3.10 with Anaconda

I tried to web scrape an internet site but get an error message

Comment: AFAIK:  website you are trying to scrape is 1) using self-signed certificate 2) has expired certificate or 3) issuer of the certificate is not valid anymore ..  None of these is anything you can do anything about  except disable the cert verification *unless* its your own site  or you have contact to the site maintainer; in both cases, cert should be regenerated ..

Comment: @rasjani gave you a good start on the answer.  It is also possible that the cert was signed by a root cert that is not part of the certs that python uses (it has its own cache of them).   you need to figure out which of those is the issue (openssl utility can be used to display a host certs information and with that you can know if its self-signed and whether it is with its valid dates.  since it worked one day and not the next it is probably an expired cert that needs to be replaced on the host you are connecting to

Comment: @LhasaDad  "since it worked one day and not the next it is probably an expired cert that needs to be replaced on the host you are connecting to"...What should I do then to replace ?

Comment: @jacques do you control that host and its http(s) serving process?  if so you will need to read up on how to add/replace certs there.   I would use openssl to check the details of the host cert to see if it is really expired.  you should be able to google or search on stackoverflow for how to check validity of a cert.

Comment: i do not have any control on the website. Do you mean that they change something from their site that caused the error message ? So it is not of my responsibility ? So should I continue to use : requests.post(url,                 headers=headers, data=data, verify=False) even if on some site I read that it is not a long term solution ?

Comment: @jacques their host certificate could have expired (they typically are good for 1 year these days)  that would cause the requests package to not trust the certificate and give you that error when verify=False is not passed in.  They could also have replaced their host certificate with a new one that was signed by a root CA certificate that the requests package does not know about.

Comment: @jacques it is generally better to get the certificate issues figured out.  But I have definitely written python that used the verify=False to deal with self signed host certificates.  It just depends on how much trust you have on the connection to the target host,  if high level of trust that it will be a direct connection to the right host then you can tolerate having the verify=False in the code.